# Preserving database contents Update fields but faced flask db migrate -m ImportError: No module named flask_babel

Tags: python, linux, database, migration, database-migration

I am Preserving database contents Update fields

doing

1. sudo systemctl restart mysql
2. pipenv shell
3. flask db history
4. mysql -u root -p erack
5. select * from alembic_version;
6. exit
7. flask db migrate -m "YOUR MESSAGE"

but facing:
**flask db migrate -m ImportError: No module named flask_babel**

```
mcsadmin@mcsadmin-VirtualBox:~/UI_Mgmt$ flask db migrate -m "YOUR MESSAGE"
 * Tip: There are .env or .flaskenv files present. Do "pip install python-dotenv" to use them.
Usage: flask db migrate [OPTIONS]

Error: While importing "app", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mcsadmin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/mcsadmin/UI_Mgmt/app/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from flask_babel import Babel
ImportError: No module named flask_babel

mcsadmin@mcsadmin-VirtualBox:~/UI_Mgmt$ pip install python-dotenv
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting python-dotenv
  Downloading python_dotenv-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: typing; python_version < "3.5" in /home/mcsadmin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from python-dotenv) (3.10.0.0)
Installing collected packages: python-dotenv
Successfully installed python-dotenv-0.18.0
mcsadmin@mcsadmin-VirtualBox:~/UI_Mgmt$ flask db migrate -m "YOUR MESSAGE"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mcsadmin/.local/bin/flask", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/mcsadmin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 967, in main
    cli.main(args=sys.argv[1:], prog_name="python -m flask" if as_module else None)
  File "/home/mcsadmin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 586, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mcsadmin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/mcsadmin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/mcsadmin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/mcsadmin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/mcsadmin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mcsadmin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mcsadmin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 425, in decorator
    with __ctx.ensure_object(ScriptInfo).load_app().app_context():
  File "/home/mcsadmin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 388, in load_app
    app = locate_app(self, import_name, name)
  File "/home/mcsadmin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/mcsadmin/UI_Mgmt/agv.py", line 1, in <module>
    from upgradation import check_UI_Mgmt_version
  File "/home/mcsadmin/UI_Mgmt/upgradation.py", line 8
    def check_version_needed_update(current_version: str, update_version: str):
                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I followed the console suggestion `pip install python-dotenv` but still face the error, how can I deal with this

Answer (score 1):

You are using the Python 2 interpreter. Please try switching to Python 3 and make sure to install all the necessary libraries in the Python 3 environment.

Answer (score 0):

my　`pipenv shell` typed in, but not work, so that time I wasn't into virtual version yet

re-type `pipenv shell` , then `flask db migrate -m "YOUR any  MESSAGE"` is work